# Urysohn Lemma for locally compact metric space: showing convergence of a finite union of ball covers to a compact set

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a locally compact metric space and $\epsilon>0$ and fix a compact set $K$. We cover $K$ with relatively compact open balls $B_{\epsilon(x)}(x)$ such that $\epsilon(x)\le \epsilon;$ at this point we use local compactness of $X$. Since $K$ is compact, there are finitely many  points $x_1,\dots, x_n \in K$ such that $$K \subset \cup_{i=1}^n B_{\epsilon(x_i)}(x_i)=:U_\epsilon.$$ Obviously, $K_\epsilon:=\cup_{i=1}^n \overline{B_{\epsilon(x_i)}}(x_i)$ is compact, $U_{\epsilon} \subset K_\epsilon$ and $U_\epsilon \to K$. In this case why is $U_\epsilon \to K$?

I think the limit here means $\cap_{\epsilon>0} \cup_{\epsilon(x_i)\le \epsilon} \cup_{i=1}^n B_{\epsilon(x_i)}$ but I can't show why an element of this set belongs to $K$. Actually the limit would not be the above since the points $x_i$ would not be the same as $\epsilon \to 0$. So this makes the problem even more confusing for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it simply means the following

$$ \mathcal{U}:=\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} 
U_{\varepsilon} = K $$

But of course, $U_{\varepsilon}$ is not uniquely determined (which I believe is your concern when you say the $x_i$'s might change) but to overcome this, we simply assume we are given $U_\varepsilon$ for each $\varepsilon>0$ which satisfies your constraints, then this can be applied to any arbitrary choice of a $U_{\varepsilon}$ family.

Then since $$K\subseteq U_{\varepsilon}$$ for any $\varepsilon$, we have

$$K\subseteq \mathcal{U} $$

To prove the other inclusion, suppose there is some $x_0\in \mathcal{U}$ which is not in $K$, then letting $\varepsilon_0 = d(x_0,K)$, which satisfies $\varepsilon_0>0$ by the compactness of $K$, we see that

$$ x_0 \notin U_{\varepsilon_0} $$

Hence

$$x_0\notin \mathcal{U} $$

A contradiction, so

$$ K=\mathcal{U} $$

(I am not super confident in this proof, particularly because it was not used at all that the balls are relatively compact, or that the space is locally compact, perhaps someone can point out an unjustified step if there is one)